# ListView doesn't show all items

Tags: java, android, listview

I'm nearly finished with my App!
It's working fine, but there's a little mistake in it..

My App is an "Note"-App with some notes that are prefabricated and are the first opening of the app.
Therefore I save this notes at the first start and get them everytime I start the app again.
Unfortunately I'm have 66 prefabricated notes and they are all saved, but in the ListView there are only 45 or so in it..

I don't think it's something with syntax because the app works fine except the loss of 21 prefabricated notes

Here's my MainActivity Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean useDarkTheme = preferences.getBoolean(PREF_DARK_THEME, false);
    SharedPreferences prefers = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefs_daten", MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (useDarkTheme) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_dark);
    }

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (VERBOSE) Log.v(TAG, "+ ON CREATE +");
    setContentView(layout.activity_hauptmenu);

    mListNotes = findViewById(id.listview);

    itemTitel = new ArrayList<>();
    itemTitel.addAll(Arrays.asList(string.Titel1, string.Titel2, string.Titel3, ...
            string.Titel66));
    itemStory = new ArrayList<>();
    itemStory.addAll(Arrays.asList(string.Blackstory1, ...));
    itemLosung = new ArrayList<>();
    itemLosung.addAll(Arrays.asList(string.Losung1, ..));
}

private void StandardBS() {
    if (Listensize==0){
        anzahl_BS=66;
        int a;
        for(a=0; a<anzahl_BS; a++){

            try{
                tempTitel = getResources().getString(itemTitel.get(a));
                tempStory = getResources().getString(itemStory.get(a));
                tempLosung = getResources().getString(itemLosung.get(a));
                Blackstory blackstory = new Blackstory(System.currentTimeMillis(), tempTitel, tempStory, tempLosung);
                Log.w("Blackstory", ""+tempTitel);
                Utilities.saveBlackstory(this, blackstory);
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Blackstory wurde gespeichert!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Standard wurde falsch ausgeführt", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        Log.w("Anzahl", ""+a);
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        try{
            mListNotes.setAdapter(null);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "not null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        final ArrayList<Blackstory> blackstories = Utilities.getAllSavedBlackstory(getApplicationContext());
        Listensize=blackstories.size();
        anzahl_BS=Listensize;
        if(blackstories != null && blackstories.size() > 0) { //check if we have any notes!
            na = new BlackstoryAdapter(this, layout.item_layout1, blackstories);
            try{
                mListNotes.setAdapter(na);
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Irgendwas ist falsch2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        //set click listener for items in the list, by clicking each item the note should be loaded into NoteActivity
            try{
                mListNotes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    //run the NoteActivity in view/edit mode
                        fileName = ((Blackstory) mListNotes.getItemAtPosition(position)).getDateTime()
                                + Utilities.FILE_EXTENSION;
                        Intent viewBlackstoryIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), number1.class);
                        viewBlackstoryIntent.putExtra(Utilities.EXTRAS_NOTE_FILENAME, fileName);
                        startActivity(viewBlackstoryIntent);
                    }
                });

                mListNotes.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
                            //ask user if he really wants to delete the note!
                            Dialog_delete(position, id);
                            return true;
            }});}

            catch (NullPointerException e){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Irgendwas ist falsch3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }}
         else { //remind user that we have no notes!
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "you have no saved notes!\ncreate some new notes :)"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    firstOpen=false;
}
```

My Utilities (to save and load notes):

```
public class Utilities {

public static final String FILE_EXTENSION = ".bin";
public static final String EXTRAS_NOTE_FILENAME = "EXTRAS_NOTE_FILENAME";

public static boolean saveBlackstory(Context context, Blackstory blackstory){
    String fileName = String.valueOf(blackstory.getDateTime()) + FILE_EXTENSION;

    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    try{
        fos = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(blackstory);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("Failed","");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public static ArrayList<Blackstory> getAllSavedBlackstory(Context context) {
    ArrayList<Blackstory> blackstories = new ArrayList<>();

    File filesDir = context.getFilesDir();
    ArrayList<String> blackstoryFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    int size = blackstoryFiles.size();
    //add .bin files to the noteFiles list
    for(String file : filesDir.list()) {

        if(file.endsWith(FILE_EXTENSION)) {
            blackstoryFiles.add(file);
            Log.w("Included", ""+file);
        }
    }
    //read objects and add to list of notes
    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;

    for (int i = 0; i < blackstoryFiles.size(); i++) {
        try{
            fis = context.openFileInput(blackstoryFiles.get(i));
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            blackstories.add((Blackstory)ois.readObject());
            fis.close();
            ois.close();

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
    return blackstories;
}
public static Blackstory getBlackstoryByFileName(Context context, String fileName) {

    File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName);
    if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) { //check if file actually exist

        Log.v("UTILITIES", "File exist = " + fileName);

        FileInputStream fis;
        ObjectInputStream ois;

        try { //load the file
            fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            Blackstory note = (Blackstory) ois.readObject();
            fis.close();
            ois.close();

            return note;

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

public static boolean deleteFile(Context context, String fileName) {
    File dirFiles = context.getFilesDir();
    File file = new File(dirFiles, fileName);

    if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) {
        return file.delete();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And my Adapter:

```
public class BlackstoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Blackstory> {

public static final int WRAP_CONTENT_LENGTH = 50;

public BlackstoryAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Blackstory> blackstories) {
    super(context, resource, blackstories);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_layout1, null);
    }

    Blackstory blackstory = getItem(position);

    if(blackstory != null) {
        TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.single_titel);

        title.setText(blackstory.getTitel());

    }

    return convertView;
}
```

My Blackstory.java:

```
public class Blackstory implements Serializable {
private String mTitel;
private String mStory;
private String mLosung;
private long mDateTime;

public Blackstory(long dateInMills, String titel, String story, String losung) {
    mDateTime = dateInMills;
    mTitel = titel;
    mStory = story;
    mLosung = losung;
}

public void setDateTime(long dateTime) {
    mDateTime = dateTime;
}

public long getDateTime() {
    return mDateTime;
}

public String getDateTimeFormatted(Context context) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
            , context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
    return formatter.format(new Date(mDateTime));
}

public String getTitel() {
    return mTitel;
}

public void setTitel(String titel) {
    mTitel = titel;
}

public String getStory() {
    return mStory;
}

public void setStory(String story) {
    mStory = story;
}

public String getLosung() {
    return mLosung;
}

public void setLosung(String losung) {
    mLosung = losung;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the code for getCount() Adapter method?

Comment: What do you mean with getCount()?

Comment: I'm using a for-loop with the number of 66 to save the exact number

Comment: The adapter must tell the list view how many items to populate using its getCount() method, that's why it is important. How have you implemented it?

Comment: Have you checked first what is the size of blackstoryFiles.size() in your loop to make sure it is 66?

Comment: I will check in 5 hours, but I thought I checked the size of "blackstoryfiles"

Comment: The size of blackstoryFiles is also 45

Comment: Then it seems you have 45 ".bin" files that you are adding to blackstoryFiles ArrayList in your for loop and not 66 as you suggest, maybe there are some files with ".BIN" instead of ".bin"?

Comment: All of the Files are added by the method saveBlackstory() in Utilities with ".bin". The prefabricated files are all added in the MainActivity by the method Utilities.saveBlackstory().

Comment: How can I check which files are in blackstoryFiles? I don't know if there are only .bin in it

Comment: Where is the implementation for getDateTime() method?

Comment: In the Blackstory.java (I added it to the question above)

Comment: It seems that your loop for saving the files sets the value of `anzahl_BS` to 66 only when `Listensize==0`, so if there is at least one file created `anzahl_BS` will not be 66, either change your logic or set `Listensize<66`

Comment: It seems that your loop for saving the files sets the value of `anzahl_BS` to 66 only when `Listensize==0`, so if there is at least one file created `anzahl_BS` will not be 66, either change your logic or set `Listensize<66`

Comment: I tried it, but the same problem occurs.. The App is displaying 45 notes perfectly in the ListView, but some are missing and those aren't always the same! The prefabricated 66 notes only are added if the app wasn't lauched before, therefore Listensize should be 0

Comment: I don't know where the problem is @AguThadeus

Answer (score 1):

There need not be getCount() method as pointed out by AguThadeus. The array data is passed to the superclass so that will take care of the number of views.

Comment: Though i strongly suggest to have that method explicitly defined.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: uhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh no.